# Find if the series absolute or conditionally convergese.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider if the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Bigr(\frac{\ln(n!)}{\ln((2n)!)}\Bigl)^nx^n$$ converges absolute or conditionally.

Using root test I found that for $|x| < 2$ series converges absolute and for $|x| > 2$ series does not converges. All thats left is to consider case $|x|=2$, but it causes some problems for me.

Comment: Try Stirling’s formula.

Comment: I used Stirling's formula in root test, but as i mentioned the only results that I get are for $|x| \neq 2$.

Comment: $\ln{2\frac{\ln{n!}}{\ln{(2n)!}}}=\ln{\frac{\ln{n}-1+o(\ln(n)/n)}{\ln{n}+\ln{2}-1+o(ln(n)/n)}} \sim -(\ln{2})\ln(n)^{-1}$, so for $|x|=2$ your sequence is rapidly decreasing to $0$ so absolutely convergent.